# Wordpress Category.php not showing all posts in that cateogry

Tags: wordpress

I am having an issue with my category showing all post from that category. My code is here: [Category Loop](http://pastebin.com/y6Gp1Xjk)

I have it set up to show my posts in 3 columns. [You can see it in action here](http://inlandbride.com/category/vendors/). There are like 48 posts that should show up, but for some reason I only get 10.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

10 is the default value of the query variable posts_per_page. You use have_posts() and the internal Wordpress mechanisms to retrieve posts, hence you are limited by this number. You can change it like this:

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=50' );
```

See this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts